# audio decoding error using libavcodec avcodec_decode_audio4

Tags: audio-recording, libavcodec

At present, I am trying audio decoding for the first time using avcodec_decode_audio4(), which is always returning error.

Note: My overall intention is to merge multiple AMR_NB encoded files into one audio file, and eventually mux this final audio file with another video file into .mp4 container.

Here's the code:

```
   if(avformat_open_input(&sound, "/tmp/aud0", NULL, NULL)!=0) {                                                 
      printf("Error in opening input file aud0\n");
      exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("Opened aud0 into FormatContext\n");
    }

    if(avformat_find_stream_info(sound, NULL)<0){
      printf("Error in finding stream info\n");
      avformat_close_input(&sound);
      exit(1);
    }

    int aud_stream_idx=-1;
    for(int count=0; count<sound->nb_streams; count++) {
      if(sound->streams[count]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        aud_stream_idx = count;        
        printf("Audio stream index %d found\n", count);
        break;
      }
    }
    if(aud_stream_idx==-1) {
      printf("Audio stream not found in the aud0 file\n");
      avformat_close_input(&sound);
      exit(1);
    }

    AVCodecContext *audioCC = sound->streams[aud_stream_idx]->codec;
    printf("Audio codec_id=%d, codec_name=%s\n", audioCC->codec_id, audioCC->codec_name);

    AVCodec *audioC = avcodec_find_decoder(audioCC->codec_id);
    if (audioC == NULL) {     printf("Couldn't find decoder\n");
      avformat_close_input(&sound);
      exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("Found decoder name %s\n", audioCC->codec_name);
    }

    if(avcodec_open2(audioCC, audioC, NULL)<0) {
      printf("Couldn't open decoder\n");
      avformat_close_input(&sound);
      exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("Found decoder name %s\n", audioCC->codec_name);
      printf("Found bitrate %d\n", audioCC->bit_rate);
      printf("Found sample_rate %d\n", audioCC->sample_rate);
      printf("Found sample_fmt %d\n", audioCC->sample_fmt);  }

    /* decode until eof */
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    avpkt.data=NULL;
    avpkt.size=0;
    if(av_read_frame(sound, &avpkt)<0) {
      printf("Couldn't read encoded audio packet\n");
      av_free_packet(&avpkt);
      avformat_close_input(&sound);
      exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("Read encoded audio packet\n");
      printf("avpkt.pts = %d\n", avpkt.pts);
      printf("avpkt.dts = %d\n", avpkt.dts);
      printf("avpkt.duration = %d\n", avpkt.duration);      
      printf("avpkt.stream_index = %d\n", avpkt.stream_index);
      printf("avpkt.data = %x\n", avpkt.data);
      printf("avpkt.data[0] = %02x\n", avpkt.data[0]);
      printf("avpkt.data[0]>>>3&0x0f = %02x\n", avpkt.data[0]>>3 & 0x0f);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "avpkt.size=%d\n", avpkt.size);
    while (avpkt.size > 0) {
        int got_frame = 0;

        if (!decoded_frame) {
            if (!(decoded_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame())) {
                fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                exit(1);
            }       } else
          avcodec_get_frame_defaults(decoded_frame);


        len = avcodec_decode_audio4(audioCC, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
        if (len < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error %d while decoding\n", len);
            exit(1);
        }
```

Here is the output I see (I think demuxing is working fine):

```
Opened aud0 into FormatContext
Audio stream index 0 found
Audio codec_id=73728, codec_name=
Found decoder name 
Found decoder name 
Found bitrate 5200
Found sample_rate 8000
Found sample_fmt 3
Read encoded audio packet
avpkt.pts = 0
avpkt.dts = 0
avpkt.duration = 160
avpkt.stream_index = 0
avpkt.data = 91e00680
avpkt.data[0] = 04
avpkt.data[0]>>>3&0x0f = 00
avpkt.size=13
[amrnb @ 0x7fce9300bc00] Corrupt bitstream
Error -1094995529 while decoding
```

This audio was created by recording voice on an Android device.

I also tried a .m4a generated by QuickTime, but no luck.

I feel I am missing some crucial step (like not initializing some CodecContext field, or not reading into AVPacket properly). In any case, if someone has any input or similar example, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

To help others understand ffmpeg error codes, this may be helpful.   Error codes from ffmpeg (error.h from avutil) :
http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/error_8h_source.html

It turns out the value you specified is :

```
#define AVERROR_INVALIDDATA        FFERRTAG( 'I','N','D','A')
```

The -1094995529 becomes -0x41444E49 and when you look at those letters, in ACSII, 0x41 = 'A', 0x44 = 'D', 0x4E = 'N, and 0x49 = 'I'.   Due to the macro/etc things are reversed, so ADNI becomes INDA, which you can see from the #define snippet, is the AVERROR_INVALIDDATA defined FFERRTAG( 'I','N','D','A').

The rest of the error codes are in that file and I've pasted them below here :

```
#define AVERROR_BSF_NOT_FOUND      FFERRTAG(0xF8,'B','S','F') ///< Bitstream filter not found
#define AVERROR_BUG                FFERRTAG( 'B','U','G','!') ///< Internal bug, also see AVERROR_BUG2
#define AVERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL   FFERRTAG( 'B','U','F','S') ///< Buffer too small
#define AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND  FFERRTAG(0xF8,'D','E','C') ///< Decoder not found
#define AVERROR_DEMUXER_NOT_FOUND  FFERRTAG(0xF8,'D','E','M') ///< Demuxer not found
#define AVERROR_ENCODER_NOT_FOUND  FFERRTAG(0xF8,'E','N','C') ///< Encoder not found
#define AVERROR_EOF                FFERRTAG( 'E','O','F',' ') ///< End of file
#define AVERROR_EXIT               FFERRTAG( 'E','X','I','T') ///< Immediate exit was requested; the called function should not be restarted
#define AVERROR_EXTERNAL           FFERRTAG( 'E','X','T',' ') ///< Generic error in an external library
#define AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND   FFERRTAG(0xF8,'F','I','L') ///< Filter not found
#define AVERROR_INVALIDDATA        FFERRTAG( 'I','N','D','A') ///< Invalid data found when processing input
#define AVERROR_MUXER_NOT_FOUND    FFERRTAG(0xF8,'M','U','X') ///< Muxer not found
#define AVERROR_OPTION_NOT_FOUND   FFERRTAG(0xF8,'O','P','T') ///< Option not found
#define AVERROR_PATCHWELCOME       FFERRTAG( 'P','A','W','E') ///< Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
#define AVERROR_PROTOCOL_NOT_FOUND FFERRTAG(0xF8,'P','R','O') ///< Protocol not found
#define AVERROR_STREAM_NOT_FOUND   FFERRTAG(0xF8,'S','T','R') ///< Stream not found
#define AVERROR_BUG2               FFERRTAG( 'B','U','G',' ')
#define AVERROR_UNKNOWN            FFERRTAG( 'U','N','K','N') ///< Unknown error, typically from an external library
#define AVERROR_EXPERIMENTAL       (-0x2bb2afa8) ///< Requested feature is flagged experimental. Set strict_std_compliance if you really want to use it.
#define AVERROR_INPUT_CHANGED      (-0x636e6701) ///< Input changed between calls. Reconfiguration is required. (can be OR-ed with AVERROR_OUTPUT_CHANGED)
#define AVERROR_OUTPUT_CHANGED     (-0x636e6702) ///< Output changed between calls. Reconfiguration is required. (can be OR-ed with AVERROR_INPUT_CHANGED)
#define AVERROR_HTTP_BAD_REQUEST   FFERRTAG(0xF8,'4','0','0')
#define AVERROR_HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED  FFERRTAG(0xF8,'4','0','1')
#define AVERROR_HTTP_FORBIDDEN     FFERRTAG(0xF8,'4','0','3')
#define AVERROR_HTTP_NOT_FOUND     FFERRTAG(0xF8,'4','0','4')
#define AVERROR_HTTP_OTHER_4XX     FFERRTAG(0xF8,'4','X','X')
#define AVERROR_HTTP_SERVER_ERROR  FFERRTAG(0xF8,'5','X','X')
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to call av_read_frame until you get to EOF. So you need av_read_frame in the loop.

Let me explain how decoding works:
you open formatcontext, codeccontext and decoder. that is the easy part.
in a loop you read packets form one stream. so you need

```
while(av_read_frame(sound, &avpkt))
```

in this loop you want to decode the data from the packet. but care, you need to check from which stream the data in the packet is. so its always better to check if the packet contains data from the audiostream

```
if (avpkt.stream_index == aud_stream_idx)
```

now you can decode and process the audio.

exmaple:

```
AVFrame * decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVPacket avpkt;
av_init_packet(&avpkt);
avpkt.data = NULL;
avpkt.size = 0;
while(av_read_frame(sound, &avpkt))
{
    if (avpkt.stream_index == aud_stream_idx)
    {
        int got_frame;
        int len = avcodec_decode_audio4(audioCC, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
    }
}
```

Thats all the the magic :)

PS: to find a stream just call

```
av_find_best_stream(sound, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, NULL, 0)
```

PPS: did not tested code. just codec here in window :D
PPPS: read the examples. [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html) helped me a lot :)